# Change the selected value of a dropdown in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, radiobuttonlist, dropdown

I have a `dropdown` of which i want to change it's selected value using JavaScript. I have `radioButtonList`, when I click one of them , it calls a function that takes the value of the selected `radioButton` and should put it in the selected value of the `dropdown`.

This is the radioButtonList :

```
<td>
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblFillButtonCategory" onclick="changeCategory()" runat="server" Width="100%">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
                        </td>
```

This is the dropdown:

```
  <td style="width: 15%;">
                                        <asp:Label ID="CategoryLabel" AssociatedControlID="DropCategory" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:SharedIssueProperties, CategoryLabel %>" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width: 35%;">
                                        <it:PickCategory ID="DropCategory" DisplayDefault="true" Required="false" runat="Server" />
                                    </td>
```

This is the Function:

```
   function changeCategory() {
        var radioButtons = document.getElementById("<% =rblFillButtonCategory.ClientID %>");
        var radiovalues = radioButtons.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var Checkdvalue;
        for (var i = 0; i < radiovalues.length; i++) {
            if (radiovalues[i].checked) {
                Checkdvalue = radiovalues[i].value;
                break;
            }
        }
        var element = document.getElementById("<% =DropCategory.ClientID %>");
        element.value = Checkdvalue;

    }
```

The problem is that the element is empty.
It means that the problem is with the `dropdown`. The code with issue:

```
document.getElementById("<% =DropCategory.ClientID %>");
```

EDIT:
I Tried another way :

```
var element = $("[id$='ddlComps']");
```

It works but i cant reach the options of the ddl.

Thanks for the help (:

Comment: View source and see what they call the fields

Comment: didnt understand what you meant

Comment: It may help if you can paste in the generated HTML from your ASP controls, so that we can see what is being rendered on the page. @ziveliyahu

Comment: Is the function code (start with `function changeCategory() {`) in external javascript file or in the `.aspx` file?

Comment: I Tried another way :    var element = $("[id$='ddlComps']");
it works but i cant reach the options